# MediaWiki Multi Site + Memcached

Tags: memcached, mediawiki

I have multiple mediawiki installations, and I'm wondering if it's safe to allow them to all use the same memcached server.

Are there any "gotchas" involved?

Answer (score 0):

The cache keys are prefixed by the database name and table prefix (or more specifically, $wgCachePrefix or if not specified wfWikiId()), so if all wikis use different database names/table prefixes then there should be no problems.